# How to use ZAPI to automaticaly update jenkins test results to zephyr by checking zephyr test ID

Tags: jenkins, jira, uft14, jira-zephyr

WE have UFT automated scripts configured in jenkins.Currently trying to achieve the automatic updation of jenkins execution status to Zephyr.
I have to update the test cycle each and evrytime in the jenkins build to make this process happen.We have different test cycle for each regresion cycle and would like to track all details.
How Can i achieve-able to update jenkins execution status in zephyr without having to update build details everytime.